# AEM with Unified highlighter

Tags: solr

[image]I am using solr 7.4.0 and using the unified highlighter. With the unified highlighter it's not giving proper results, the query is not highlighting all the pages. I wanna continue with  highlighter if someone can help me to solve this issue.

Here is my configuration:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="hl.method">unified</str>
    <int name="hl.snippets">1</int>
    <str name="hl.tag.pre"><em></str>
    <str name="hl.tag.post"></em></str>
    <str name="hl.simple.pre"><em></str>
    <str name="hl.simple.post"></em></str>
    <str name="hl.tag.ellipsis">... </str> 
    <bool name="hl.defaultSummary">true</bool>
    <str name="hl.encoder">simple</str> 
    <float name="hl.score.k1">1.2</float>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
 <str name="hl.method">unified</str>
 <int name="hl.snippets">1</int>
 <str name="hl.tag.pre"><em></str>
 <str name="hl.tag.post"></em></str>
 <str name="hl.simple.pre"><em></str>
 <str name="hl.simple.post"></em></str>
 <str name="hl.tag.ellipsis">... </str>
 <bool name="hl.defaultSummary">true</bool>
 <str name="hl.encoder">simple</str>
 <float name="hl.score.k1">1.2</float>
 
 
 </lst>
 </requestHandler>

Comment: this is my config please help me how to do it

Comment: What's AEM? What's wrong with the response you're getting?

Comment: @MatsLindh : AEM is a content management solution for building websites...AEM comes with in built solr as well

Comment: hi @AbhijitBashetti some of the  results highlighting and some or not. can you please provide page fragmentation not happeing. solr side config change let me know.thanks

Comment: image contains one results with bold and one record with out bold,the page actually contains searched word but not  fetching the word sentence.

Comment: try by increasing the fragment size

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: HI  Abhijit Bashetti  fragment size not supporting for unified highlighter.